# Trying to delay the execution of js script, but changes don't show on screen

Tags: javascript, html

I have these lines on my code:

```
           arrR[iR].elmnt.style.background = "#ff7f7f";
           copyz[startIndex].elmnt.style.background = "#ffff7f";

           wait(500);
           
           copyz[startIndex].elmnt.innerHTML = arrR[iR].value;

           arrR[iR].elmnt.style.background = "#fff";
           copyz[startIndex].elmnt.style.background = "#fff";
```

Basically what I trying to do is for an element to change its background color > wait for some time > change its inner HTML and bring its background color back to white.

However, during the process, the changes doesn't show up on screen, but you can see the innerHTML changing through the Developer Tools. Can someone explain why it is happening?

My wait function is this:

```
 function wait(ms) {
    var d = new Date();
    var d2 = null;
    do {
        d2 = new Date();
    }
    while (d2 - d < ms);
}
```

Comment: What is “wait”? That’s not a function in js. And you aren’t getting anywhere by skipping vowels like in “ elmnt“.

Comment: You could simply use CSS and  @keyframes Amination.

Answer (score 1):

You have an potentially infinite loop inside that `wait` function. I suggest to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Make `wait()` return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which *Resolves* in the setTimeout callback.
Than you can write *linearly* your *"execute, **Await**, execute, ..."* markup, but in that case it must be contained inside an **Async** function

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function changeColors() {

  document.body.style.background = "#0bf";
  await wait(500);
  
  document.body.style.background = "#f0b";
  await wait(500);

  changeColors(); // If you want to loop
}

changeColors();
```

- [Async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Scope.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)